# Domain issues with outlook? (receiving issues using outlook)

Tags: outlook

I'm currently using Samba to create usernames for windows 8.1

The user I created was able to login to the domain properly. but the only problem is that whenever you wanted to use Outlook as your e-mail client it seems to have issues receiving e-mails(Authentication issues). what is more strange is that when you use a different e-mail program(thunderbird) it seems to work properly.

I tried re-creating the profile and the user on my server side but it seems to be the same issue.

Here are some logs from Dovecot IP address and e-mail address is hidden for security reasons.

```
Oct 15 11:48:30 dynamails dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#01112237#011PLAIN#011service=pop3#011lip=192.168.XXX.XXX#011rip=192.168.XXX.XXX#011lport=110#011rport=49671#011resp=<hidden>
Oct 15 11:48:30 dynamails dovecot: auth: Debug: sql(myTest@Mydomain.com,192.168.XXX.XXX): query: SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'myTest@Mydomain.com' AND active = '1'
Oct 15 11:48:30 dynamails dovecot: auth: sql(myTest@Mydomain.com,192.168.XXX.XXX): Password mismatch
Oct 15 11:48:32 dynamails dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<myTest@Mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.XXX.XXX, lip=192.168.XXX.XXX
Oct 15 11:49:02 dynamails dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#01124556#011PLAIN#011service=pop3#011lip=192.168.1.250#011rip=192.168.XXX.XXX#011lport=110#011rport=49673#011resp=<hidden>
Oct 15 11:49:02 dynamails dovecot: auth: Debug: sql(myTest@Mydomain.com,192.168.XXX.XXX): query: SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'myTest@Mydomain.com' AND active = '1'
Oct 15 11:49:02 dynamails dovecot: auth: sql(myTest@Mydomain.com,192.168.XXX.XXX): Password mismatch
Oct 15 11:49:04 dynamails dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<myTest@Mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.XXX.XXX, lip=192.168.XXX.XXX
```

Here is the error from outlook

When you setup the account there is a part where you can test the e-mail settings and once you clicked that it will ask again for the password and when you type the password it will give you this error.

```
Log onto incoming mail server (POP3): Your e-mail server rejected your login. verify your user name and password for this account in Account Settings. The server responded: -ERR Authentication failed.
```

I'm a bit confused to this as the same settings worked in thunderbird and on on another PC with a working profile.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: At the very least, we'd need some logs showing what is actually happening. "Doesn't work" is not much to go on.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I added the error messages im seeing in the server side and the client side. as far as I checked i have not seen any other error messages besides these 2.